# in c, is there a proper way to explain this (example in post) loop actions order and does it affect different actions as well?

Tags: c, loops, operator-precedence, command-precedence

im a mechanical engineering student doing a course in c so my question here is less about actually helping with coding and more about understanding the logic of the actions in the program (since thats the test i will be given).

this post comes from [image: this question in an example test] at first i assumed that the loop will check the condition of "n>0" before exiting the brackets so the static int inside will be checked.
but instead it will exit the } bracket first and than check, which means i went outside of the static int scope and the int will always be 3 since the decrement will affect only the static int.

tl;dr---------------------------------------------------------------------

my question about it all is, how do i explain this behavior? is there a proper explanation as to why this order happens so that i would be able to use that logic to understand behavior of different snippets of codes using that logic?

thanks in advance

Comment: What is unclear? You already have described the logic yourself.

Comment: i explained what happened but i dont understand why was the loop condition checked only outside of the brackets. 
what im asking isnt why in this question specifically did it happen, but to why such behavior occurred and if it can explain other actions and interaction in different snippets of code. 
maybe theres other actions which there order of operations arent talked about in normal textbox operator precedence table that could affect the outcome of the code.

Comment: It is just a silly question. You already have described the logic yourself. Are you unable to understand yourself?! Read any book on C for beginners about scopes of variables.

Comment: i went over multiple textbooks and my course ppt about scopes,loops and variables but i couldnt find anywhere that talks about this behavior when reaching the end of it. 
what i dont understand is why does this action occur? i understand that it happens but i dont understand why the loop test is checked outside of the brackets.
i want to understand if its a situation of "thats how c works" or if theres a proper logic behind it that would help me in different questions in my test that in first glance will have nothing in common with this question but maybe the logic behind it will be similar

Comment: @CodeBom - The loop condition is checked outside the brackets because it **is** outside the brackets. It's really that simple.  :-)  From the inside you can look out, but from the outside you cannot look in (because the inside only exists while excuting the inside code).

Answer (score 0):

There are two different variables named `n` in `foo`.  The first is the argument `n`, which is passed in by the caller.  The second is the static declaration inside the loop body.

The `n` in the `while` test refers to the argument.  The static `n` inside the loop body is only in scope while the loop body is executing, and is never in scope when the loop test is evaluated, so the loop never exits.

If `foo` is called with `n` less than or equal to zero, the loop exits immediately and the function returns `x`.  Otherwise, if `n` is greater than zero, it enters an infinite loop.  The static `n` inside the loop body has no effect on the loop test.

Comment: so by that logic, any kind of loop/ternary operation test can only be tested on parameters which are located outside of them? ie. if the condition will check the parameter n, than the condition will check the value of n once its outside of the scope? 
so than if i use a for loop for example and start it with "int i=0", than the parameter i is considered outside of the loop scope but only exist in the loop?

Comment: @CodeBom Declarations made in the initialization portion of a `for` statement are in scope for the rest of the loop, including the test and increment portions of the `for` statement.  It's not the same as declarations made inside the loop body.

Answer (score -1):

I think the term you are looking for is "Variable shadowing"

Variable shadowing happens when your program have multiple variables with the same name.

Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int x = 42;  <--- variable with name x

void foo(void)
{
    printf("%d\n", x);  <-- which x variable is being printed here
}

void bar(int x)   <--- variable with name x
{
    printf("%d\n", x);  <-- which x variable is being printed here
}

int main(void)
{
    int x = 1;    <--- variable with name x
    printf("%d\n", x);  <-- which x variable is being printed here
    foo();
    bar(1234);
}
```

The output here will be:

```
1
42
1234
```

because

- The local variable `x` in `main` is shadowing the global variable `x`
- The local variable `x` in `bar` is shadowing the global variable `x`

In a given (block) scope it's the last definition of the variable `x`that determines  which `x` variable that are being used.

In your program the `int static n` variable inside the body of the `while` is shadowing the `int n` variable (aka parameter) of `foo`. In other words - inside the `while` body `n` refers to the `int static n` variable and outside the `while` body `n` refers to the `int n` variable/function parameter.

You can read more here: [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing#:~:text=In%20computer%20programming%2C%20variable%20shadowing,is%20known%20as%20name%20masking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing#:%7E:text=In%20computer%20programming%2C%20variable%20shadowing,is%20known%20as%20name%20masking).